# How to have the log history of the inserted event in the Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a Google Calendar, where a set of collegues are enabled to insert events.

I'm looking for a way to trace the event insertion, so I can know who and when the event was inserted.

I surfed the web, but it seems the the only way to achieve these info is to have at least a business edition.

Is there anyone can which can help or give an hint?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the only way to achieve this would be using the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest) since the Calendar API has no watch method for this and you would not need a higher subscription for it as well.

I did this short sample script in Google Apps Script that compares if an event has been created  and sends a separate email with  information such as the email address of the person that created the event and the timestamp of when the event was created.

Ideally it should be run by a trigger every day, or the script can be improved  so that the trigger runs every couple minutes or hours or even send just a single email every day depending on your needs, but it is just an example of how you could use the Reports API to accomplish this.

```
function myFunction()
{
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(00, 00, 00, 00);
  let request = {
    "eventName": "create_event",
    "filters": "calendar_id==id12345@group.calendar.google.com" // Calendar ID of the specific calendar that you want to check
  };
  result = AdminDirectory.Activities.list("all", "calendar", request);
  for(let i = 0; i<Object.keys(result.items).length; i++)
  {
    let time = new Date(result.items[i].id.time);
    if(result.items[i].actor.email=="user@domain.com" && time >=today) // Compares the email address of the event creator (your colleagues) and the time it was created
    { 
      GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@domain.com", "Event creation alert", `Event creator: ${result.items[i].actor.email} \nTime: ${result.items[0].id.time}`);
    }
  }
}
```

References:

- [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)
- [activities.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)

Answer (score 0):

In case you just need to be informed in any readable way, then the easiest one is to **enable** a bounce **notification by email** in **calendar settings** (section "Other notifications", the "New events" dropdown)

[image: Settings example]